# On Hover, Change Opacity of Other Links

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to do the simple effect of

> Hovering over a navigation link, makes the hovered link go white while the other links lower opacity.

Though it sounds simple, I'm having a little bit of difficulty with it.

```css
.nav-link:hover
{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
}

.nav-link:hover .nav-link
{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,.75) !important;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Publisher</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Advertiser</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

This is probably super simple, but I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CSS does not support previous sibling or parent selectors, there is only one way to get it to work if you want to do it the CSS-only way:

1. When the entire `.navbar-nav` element is hovered on, all `.nav-item` will fade out to, say, `opacity: 0.25`
2. When any individual `.nav-item` is hovered on, it will fade in to `opacity: 1`

However, a catchall to this method is that it is layout-dependent and only works best if the links are shrink-wrapped in a way, such that there is no empty space in the `<ul>` that is not filled by its child:

```css
.nav-item {
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-nav:hover .nav-item {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.navbar-nav:hover .nav-item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Publisher</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Advertiser</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```